# How to get the revision history of a branch with bzrlib

Tags: python, launchpad, bazaar, bzrlib

I'm trying to get a list of committers to a bzr branch. I know I can get it through the command line with something along these lines:

```
bzr log -n0 | grep committer | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*committer: //' | uniq
```

However, I'd like to get that list programmatically with `bzrlib`. After having looked at the bzrlib documentation, I can't manage to find out how I would even get the full list of revisions from my branch.

Any hints on how to get the full history of revisions from a branch with bzrlib, or ultimately, the list of committers?

Answer (score 2):

I've now found out how to do it. I'm adding code to check out a local copy of the branch, although not strictly necessary (the revision info can be read from a checked-out, local copy directly). The important bits are the `all_revision_ids()`, `get_revisions()` and `get_apparent_authors()` methods.

```
import os
from bzrlib.branch import Branch
from bzrlib.plugin import load_plugins

# The location on your file system where you want to check out
# the branch to get revisions for 
local_path = '/path/to/local/checkout'

# The name of the project you want to get the branch from
project_name = 'launchpad-project-name'

# Load the bzr plugins - the "launchpad" plugin 
# provides support for the "lp:" shortcut
load_plugins()

remote_branch_url = 'lp:{0}'.format(project_name)
remote_branch = Branch.open(remote_branch_url)

# Check out and get an instance of the branch
local_branch = remote_branch.bzrdir.sprout(
                   os.path.join(local_path,
                   project_name)).open_branch()

# Get all revisions from the branch
all_revision_ids = local_branch.repository.get_revisions(
    local_branch.repository.all_revision_ids())

# Set up a set of unique author names
authors = set()

# Iterate all revisions and get the list of authors
# without duplicates
for revision in all_revision_ids:
    for author in revision.get_apparent_authors():
        authors.add(author)

print 'Authors:', authors
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install the `bzr-stats` package and run the following command inside a branch's directory:

```
bzr stats
```